# Using wi-fi PCI-E card as a repeater

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, repeater

- My network is composed of 2 routers: Router 1 (192.168.1.1) is the internet gateway, and handles DHCP. Router 2 (192.168.1.2) has wireless capability and is connected to Router 1 via ethernet cable.
- Most devices in the house (laptops/smartphones) connect to Router 2 wirelessly, with the remaining having an ethernet connection to Router 1.
- My desktop PC is the exception, since it's at the other end of the house, too far to pass an ethernet cable through, and on the edge of wireless connectivity range. As such, I bought a pair of Powerline devices to establish a stable link between my PC and Router 1.

Everything works fine, except when I try to use my smartphone when at my PC. Since the distance to Router 2 is too high, the wireless link is simply too unstable.

Since my desktop PC has a wireless PCI-E card (not being used right now), I was wondering if there is some way I can make it work as a repeater for my wireless network, using the Powerline connection to transmit data between the main network segment and clients connected to my PC.

Considering my PC is running Windows 7, the closest I've found to this functionality is a program called Virtual Router Manager. However, this program forces me to use the wireless card for both connecting to the main segment of my network, and to repeat the signal. What I want is to use the Powerline connection to access my network, and have the wireless card act as a repeater for Router 2, so that any wireless device that comes near my PC will connect via my wireless card instead of going through Router 2. Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you want to achieve is to make your Windows 7 PC into a 'Access Point' - to share the wired-internet with neighboring devices using built in WiFi card. There are lots of ways to configure this in windows 7 & Windows 8 but the simplest i found is using a open source tool called 'Virtual Router'

To check if your wlan adapter is compatible with hostednetwork (and therefore also with VirtualRouter)

1. on command prompt type: **netsh wlan show drivers**.
2. ensure that **'Hosted network supported: Yes'** is present in output

if yes you can go ahead and download the 'Virtual Router Manager' from http://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/. configuration of 'Virtual Router' is straight forward and simple.

Comment: I have managed to establish a traffic link using Virtual Router, I only have one problem remaining: Virtual Router only works if I set an SSID that is different from my main wireless network. This means I have to manually change my devices' network whenever I move around. Is there any way to have Virtual Router use the same SSID, like a repeater would? (I tried making the SSID/password match in Virtual Router but my devices fail to connect if I do that)

Comment: Accepting your answer as I've found an acceptable workaround for the SSID problem. (all mobile devices are Android and there's an app that switches networks based on signal strength) Still would like to hear if there's any way to make things work with a single SSID, though.

Comment: there is nothing on the WiFi AP side to stop having same SSID/Password. Maybe you should delete/forget the existing saved WiFi profiles on android device and try a fresh connection to the Windows-HotSpot. that would give more clarity as to the issue.